# What is the average Left Field vs. Right Field fence distance in MLB?

Tags: baseball

All 30 parks.  Make assumptions.

I'm thinking if the Right Field value is quite a bit lower, THAT is the reason why left handed hitters *“hit better”* with low and inside pitches – something announcers oft repeat over the decades but no one has ever *yet* explained why (in my experience) and the interwebs are withholding the information just to mess with us, so we'll have to solve it for ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this graphic](http://thumbnails.visually.netdna-cdn.com/baseballs-many-physical-dimensions_53344ca673751.png), as of 2014, the average Left Field wall sits about 331 Feet from Home Plate, while the average Right Field wall sits about 328 Feet from Home Plate.  So basically they are about the same distance, I wouldn't think it'd give either side much more of an advantage.

The MLB does state that:

> The distance from home base to the nearest fence, stand or other obstruction on fair territory shall be 250 feet or more. A distance of 320 feet or more along the foul lines, and 400 feet or more to center field is preferable.

[image: Stadium Graphics]

Comment: Muey perfecto El Hefe! That is _such_ a great graphic. I'm not seeing the avg. numbers you gave (assume you did it) but the one little graphic far left shows a 45' -vs- 51' foot variance between L/R. I should think 6” is a big deal on the foul lines. Also, there seems to be a LOT more opportunity looking just beyond that 302 right and 310 left field shortest point (on the one main graphic.) Looking at that, I would MUCH rather be a left-handed hitter in the MLB, and _to my mind_ this explains clearly why a pitch thrown inside and down is more advantageous to a left handed hitter than a righty.

Comment: Note: you might edit your post and upload that graphic file as an image within your answer.  (You just provide the http link.)  That will copy the file to stackexchange servers, so the file will be here no matter what happens to that other website server/link-location.